# Error when I try to find mean in pandas version 2.0.3

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I try to find mean in pandas version 2.0.3 BUT this problem not in pandas version 0.23.3

```
df.mean()
```

I face the following error:

> ValueError: could not convert string to float

to solution this problem I use:

```
df.describe().mean()
```

What is the reason of this problem?

Comment: Could you please share us a portion of the input dataset?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like you have columns with string data type, where the `mean()` cannot be calculated on them. So, According to the [documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/2.0/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.mean.html), you can set `numeric_only=True`, which only calculates mean on numeric columns.

```
df.mean(numeric_only=True)
```

---

According to the [documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.23.3/generated/pandas.DataFrame.mean.html#pandas.DataFrame.mean) of pandas 0.23.3, the reason that you are not facing an error while using mean is the default value for `numeric_only` parameter is `None`. Here is the explanation of documentation for `numeric_only` in pandas 0.23.3 :

> numeric_only : boolean, default None
>
> Include only float, int, boolean columns. If None, will attempt to use everything,
> then use only numeric data. Not implemented for
> Series.

Where is pandas 2.0.3 the default value is `False` which means include all columns with all data types. Here is the explanation from documentation for pandas 2.0.3 :

> numeric_onlybool, default False
>
> Include only float, int, boolean columns. Not implemented for Series.

Comment: Mohsen_Fatemi thank you for your answer,BUT why this problem dont show in pandas version 0.23.3 , I try to find mean like df.mean() without use describe()  and dont have any error

Comment: in pandas 2.0.3 set numeric_only=False by default ?

Comment: Yes. it is False by default.

Comment: You can use the links that I provided and check them by yourself.

Comment: By links I meant documentation links. No need to send an invitation in linkedin.

Comment: Yes I know what you are meaning  (documentation )

Answer (score 0):

Ah. I see what happened here. Check the float values and ensure they don't contain any commas or any other characters. You want to use the .Replace function to eliminate those extra characters.

edit **
there is also the to_numeric function.

What the error is saying is that the aggregate function isn't able to work on the data because the data types don't match. This can happen when the data has rows improperly represented, not counted as floats, or otherwise contain foreign characters.

The reason is works with "Describe" is being describe by default excludes nonnumeric and NaN rows.

DataFrame.mean(axis=0, skipna=True, numeric_only=False, **kwargs)
I'm wondering if the default behavior of the Pandas .mean() function is different from earlier versions. Try setting numeric_only to true.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but my question why this problem dont show in pandas version 0.23.3 , I try to find mean like df.mean() without use describe(), this error in pandas version 2.0.3

Comment: numeric_only is set to False by default on Pandas 2, maybe set that to True?

Answer (score 0):

The problem you are having is because you are trying to average a *DataFrame* that contains non-numeric columns. *pandas' mean()* function tries to convert all data into float numbers to calculate the mean. If your DataFrame contains columns with non-numeric data (such as strings), you will get a *ValueError: could not convert string to float*.

The pandas *describe()* function, however, returns descriptive statistics only for the numeric columns of the *DataFrame*, ignoring non-numeric columns. So when you call *describe().mean()*, you are actually averaging the descriptive statistics of the numeric columns.

From the official pandas documentation [link](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.describe.html)

> For mixed data types provided via a DataFrame, the default is to
> return only an analysis of numeric columns. If the dataframe consists
> only of object and categorical data without any numeric columns, the
> default is to return an analysis of both the object and categorical
> columns. If include='all' is provided as an option, the result will
> include a union of attributes of each type.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but my question why this problem dont show in pandas version  0.23.3 , I try to find mean like df.mean() without use describe()